# get_queryset() missing 1 required positional argument: 'country_id'

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-urls

I have a list of countries they all have there own url www.example.com/al/ for example. But when I want to filter the view per country_id it gives me this error:

get_queryset() missing 1 required positional argument: 'country_id'

## My models

```
class Country(models.Model):
    COUNTRY_CHOICES = (
        ('Albania', 'Albania'),
        ('Andorra', 'Andorra'),
        # etc. etc.
)
name = models.CharField(max_length=255, choices=COUNTRY_CHOICES, default='Netherlands')

    def __str__(self):
       return self.name

class City(models.Model):
     country = models.ForeignKey(Country, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
     name = models.CharField(max_length=250)

     def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

## My Views

```
class CityOverview(generic.ListView):
template_name = 'mytemplate.html'

def get_queryset(self, country_id, *args, **kwargs):
    return City.objects.get(pk=country_id)
```

## My Urls

```
# Albania
path('al', views.CityOverview.as_view(), name='al'),

# Andorra
path('ad', views.CityOverview.as_view(), name='ad'),

# etc. etc.
```

Comment: That is *not* how you write URL patterns. And neither is it how you write the `get_queryset` method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change in several places, lets start from the models:

```
class Country(models.Model):
    COUNTRY_CHOICES = (
        ('al', 'Albania'),  # changing the first value of the touple to country code, which will be stored in DB
        ('an', 'Andorra'),
        # etc. etc.
)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, choices=COUNTRY_CHOICES, default='nl')

    def __str__(self):
       return self.name
```

Now, we need to update the url path to get the value of the country code:

```
 path('<str:country_id>/', views.CityOverview.as_view(), name='city'),
```

Here we are using `str:country_id`, as a dynamic path variable, which will accept string in the path which will be passed to the view as country_id. Meaning, whenevenever you are using for example `localhost:8000/al/`, it will pass the value `al` as country code to the view.

Finally, getting the value of the `country_id` in ListView, and using it in queryset. You can do it like this:

```
class CityOverview(generic.ListView):
    template_name = 'mytemplate.html'

    def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
        country_id = self.kwargs.get('country_id')
        return City.objects.filter(country__name=country_id)
```

You need to make sure to return a [queryset](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#queryset-api) from the `get_queryset` method, not an [object](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#get).

Comment: Thank you very much @ruddra. The self.kwargs.get('kwarg') had given me lots of trouble

Answer (score 2):

This is happening because your `urls.py` is not passing `views.py` the positional argument `country_id`. You can fix it like so:

```
path('<str:country_id>', views.CityOverview.as_view())
```

Now this path will work if the user navigates to both /al and /ad, and the string will be passed to your `CityOverview` view as a positional argument. See the [Django Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/http/urls/) on the URL Dispatcher for more info.

Comment: You need to combine this with Sergey's answer.

Answer (score 1):

Just get `country_id` from `kwargs`. For `get_queryset` you need to return `queryset` but not a single object. So use `filter` instead of `get`.

```
def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
    country_id = self.kwargs['country_id']
    return City.objects.filter(country=country_id)
```